# string.Join odd behavior

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm trying to call [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0) with the following arguments (first param is the separator):

```
string.Join(";", null, "string", 0); //returns empty string ???.
string.Join(";", null, null, 0); //returns empty string ???.
string.Join(";", null, null, null); //returns ";;;" - Good
string.Join(";", 0, 0, 0); //returns "0;0;0" - Good
string.Join(";", 0, null, 0); // "0;;0" - Good
string.Join(";", null, 0, null); // empty
```

Can anyone please explain why it acts this way? How to rely on the string.Join in such cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`String.Join(String, Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) overload is selected for the following calls:

```
string.Join(";", null, "string", 0); // empty string
string.Join(";", null, null, 0); // empty string
string.Join(";", 0, 0, 0); // "0;0;0"
string.Join(";", 0, null, 0); // "0;;0"
string.Join(";", null, 0, null); // empty string
```

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) (see *Notes to Callers*):

> If the first element of *values* is **null**, the `Join(String, Object[])`
>   method does not concatenate the elements in values but instead returns
>   `String.Empty`.

The [`String.Join(String, String[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) overload, which does not share the same implementation quirk, is selected for this call:

```
string.Join(";", null, null, null); // ";;;"
```

Comment: Argh, I checked the wrong overload before asking my question... Anyway, why did they design it so?

Answer (score 2):

From the [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,815fed0ee06a7bc8) `Join(String separator, params Object[] values)`'s  implementation

```
if (values.Length == 0 || values[0] == null)
    return String.Empty;
```

I think this is your answer.